# Visa for my Philippine wife to visit (holiday 18 days Spain)

Tags: visas, spain

My wife (Philippine national) and I were married in the UK. We want to visit Spain for 17/18 days.

We have hotels for 7 nights booked and confirmed. I received a visa application, but does anybody know if she will get a visa? I am a British passport holder and we got a visa for the UK earlier this year with no problem. I do not want to book flights until I am sure of a visa for my wife. We live mainly in Philippines and own our house.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you are a British citizen and for that reason an EU citizen. Your wife has a nationality which requires a visa to enter the Schengen area.

If you are planning to travel together, she can apply for a visa as a *family member of an EU national.* This visa has simplified documentation requirements; mostly she has to provide her family relationship.

See [Travel documents for non-EU family members](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm).

She *can* get this visa on arrival, but that is not advised because of the hassle and complications.

Comment: To get it on arrival she **must** buy a throwaway onward ticket to somewhere where she doesn't need a visa, or she's not getting on the plane

Comment: @Coke, she could also try to arrive at a land border. But you're right, that is **not** the way to go about it. She should apply for a family visa before arrival.